# Нow to send post query with variable in bash?

Tags: xml, bash, curl

I am having difficulties with sending POST query in XML using bash script. Calling the API functions is carried out by passing to the file "`functions.php`" using the POST variable method `input_xml` containing a specially formed XML.

```
curl  -X POST  -i  -F input_xml=@/app/server/input_xml http://XX.XX.X.X/api/functions.php
```

This is ok if sending the query using special utilities like Postman.
But with curl, it gives the response `"Variable input_xml is empty"` when I wait for correct answer.

```
Result

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 03 May 2019 09:16:51 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2cmhd3a0mqf7u330rpbdi3lhd0; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 114
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><document><result value="2">Variable input_xml is empty.</result></document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not actual, thanks for trying to help.
desicion:

**curl --data-urlencode input_xml@/app/informatica/PMRootDir/prod/log_motiw/input_xml.xml  -X POST http://*****/api/file.php**

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly missing content-type parameter:

`-H 'content-type: application/xml'`

Comment: problem not with this

Answer (score 0):

From the curl command manual page, I see that you have to use `@` to pass a file as is to the server (as a file upload). But if you want to pass just the content, you should use `<` symbol instead of `@` symbol

Try using `<` symbol in place of `@` symbol

Comment: i took it in one of ready scripts, i'm not sure that was correct way.

Comment: still "Variable input_xml is empty"